# SQL Sort by temporary "AS" column

Tags: sql, guptateamdeveloper, sqlbase, centura

I want to sort my result by a column that I actually create temoprarly

```
SELECT A, B, @MID(C,2,2) as X FROM foobar ORDER BY X DESC
```

I know this would work in **MySQL** but it doesn't seams to work in SQL (SQLBase).

Any suggestions?

I tried:

```
SELECT A, B, @MID(C,2,2) as X FROM foobar ORDER BY @MID(C,2,2) DESC
```

Result was **`Invalid Columnname`** same as using **`ORDER BY X`**

Comment: `order by c` should work.

Comment: ok, I have to edit my post a bit to make clear whats wrong ^^ @MID actually cuts me some digits out that I need for the ORDER BY

Comment: try 'order by @MID(C,2,2)'

Comment: I allready tried this... error. He searches for a non exisiting color

Comment: Give this a shot `select * from (SELECT A, B, @MID(C,2,2) as X FROM foobar) t order by X)`

Comment: Does column `C` exist in the table `foobar`?

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY 3`?

Comment: omg, you nailed it @Siyual !!!!! Post it I will vote it up an accept it

Comment: Can you not use a `Sub-Query` or `CTE`?

Comment: @christiandev in sql, at least in SQLBase sql its kind of difficult using sub-querys.

Comment: Caution: If at anytime columns change in your select the 3 may need to be adjusted, it's why typically order bys are column specific, not position specific.  There are always exceptions but just be aware of the risk.

Comment: Agree with @xQbert comment, this can make things fragile.

Comment: @xQbert I allready noticed this. But in my case this is not necessary. I build my select with the order by relevant column on first place and select everthing afterwards... so i wont run into this problem. Also the source I code will propably never be changed again, but as long as im not sure that a meteor falls on the earth next week, ill code it like some one may change it soon :D But thx for this hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can order by the column `ordinal` as well.  But keep in mind, if the query is modified, the `ORDER BY` clause would need to be reviewed to be sure it's ordering on the correct column.  This should work for you:

```
SELECT A, B, @MID(C,2,2) as X 
FROM foobar 
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Another option would be to use a sub-query:

```
SELECT A, B, X
FROM
(
    SELECT A, B, @MID(C,2,2) as X 
    FROM foobar 
) AS S
ORDER BY X DESC
```

Comment: my reservation with this is that an alteration to the query, say `SELECT A, B, NewCol, @MID(C,2,2) as X`, then it will order on `NewCol`

Comment: @christiandev This is true - I've also added a sub-query option as well.

Comment: @Siyual, the sub query is the way to go I think, I mentioned it above.

Comment: The Sub-Query wont work in SQLBase SQL. Actually I dont know why but it wont work :) Causes a Unknown Table Error or something like that.